# Cross-Platform bluetooth raw data transfer

Tags: ios, cordova, windows-phone-8, bluetooth, cross-platform

I want to do a simple app that can transfer any type of data between iOs, Android and Windows Phone. My idea is to transfer **raw data** and properly encode/decode it when needed. I'm considering `Cordova` to accomplish this, but i can't find any bluetooth plugin compatible with all my needed platform.

This is what i found until now:

- [Bluetooth Serial](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial) (no Windows Phone support)
- [Phonegap bluetooth Plugin](https://github.com/tanelih/phonegap-bluetooth-plugin) (Android only)
- [BluetoothLE](https://github.com/randdusing/BluetoothLE) (looks promising but i'm looking for normal bluetooth, not LE)

Is my idea really possible? Or i should use some other approach like `Xamarin`?

Comment: You can only use Bluetooth LE on iOS devices.  Apps don't have any access to legacy Bluetooth